# Profile flag history: What does the appended number represent?

Tags: support, flagging

When viewing the flag history page, I find that each entry has a number following the title of the flagged post. For instance:

[image: example flag entry]

What does the circled number represent?

Comment: I guess it's one of those moments where you have to click on the question and see where there's four of _something_ in the question :P

Comment: @KingDuken I didn’t assume it was related to responses within the post. I thought it was related to a counter of flags, or something similar - which would actually be kind of useful to know.

Comment: I believe that privilege is given to you once you reach a high enough rep a particular SE branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wondered about that myself, and I eventually concluded that it's the number of answers that the question has.

Comment: Ah ha. Never thought of that. I thought maybe it was a counter of concurrent flags, or something.